# Calling a Class Deceleration or Method Using a String Name through a function

Tags: vb.net, function

I want to do some calculations using some predefined values stored in a class by calling them as such Values.BLOCKNAME < (called from function) to retrieve that subdecleration of the class thats defined

```
'Function to calculate the full value of all the materials needed to build the blueprint
Function CalculateResourcesValue(inputblock As String, inputcount As Integer) 'WIP WIP WIP WIP WIP WIP
    Dim values As New ValuesOfBlocks 'Access the class list of ingots and component ammounts
    Dim BlockName As String = inputblock
    Dim BlockCount As Integer = inputcount

    total = BlockCount * values.blockname
    'inputcount * values.LargeBlockArmorBlockSteelPlates.ToString
End Function

'Values of materials per block type
Public Class ValuesOfBlocks
    Public LargeBlockArmorBlock As Integer = 25 'Large Light Armor Block
    Public SmallBlockArmorBlockSteelPlates As Integer = 1 'Small Light Armor Block
    Public LargeBlockArmorSlope As Integer = 13 'Large Ligth Armor Slope 
    Public SmallBlockArmorSlopeSteelPlates As Integer = 1 'Small Light Armor Slope
    Public LargeBlockArmorCorner As Integer = 4 'Large Light Armor Corner
    Public SmallBlockArmorCornerSteelPlates As Integer = 1 'Small Light Armor Corner
    Public LargeBlockArmorInvCorner As Integer = 21 'Large Light Armor Corner Inverted
    Public SmallBlockArmorInvCornerSteelPlates As Integer = 1 'Small Light Armor Corner Inverted

    'Small Blocks
End Class
```

Comment: First thing, set `Option Strict On` multiplying an integer by a string is nonsense.  I also have no idea what you mean by `subdeclaration`.  By and large it sounds like elements of OOP applied further upstream would make this easier to implement.  For instance an armour class could hold the values you need without a quasi lookup that code seems to be trying to implement.

Comment: Does the string name originate from outside your program (i.e. user input)?  If not, just define ValuesOfBlocks as a Module and make all the members constants ( i.e. `Public Const LargeBlockArmorBlock As Integer = 25`).  Accessing constants via a string lookup should be the last option pursued.

Comment: The string name isnt anything to worry about the BlockName originates from a outside file being read through the program and returning the different blocks listed in the file. This will calculate the values total based on the input through a for function if you want to have a look https://rink.hockeyapp.net/apps/480f25ed4bd14503a05891f09118961b

Input file is a space engineers blueprint file .SBC

Comment: If this is coming from an outside file, consider making a class to contain the values and a dictionary mapping block names from the file to class instances that you create as you parse the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would **strongly** suggest to take the advice of Plutonix and re-think the structure of your project.

In the meanwhile, this can be a (non elegant) solution:

add a method (or a property) to your class that returns an Integer value given a string input

```
Function CalculateResourcesValue(inputblock As String, inputcount As Integer) As Integer
    Return New ValuesOfBlocks().Value(inputblock) * inputcount

End Function

Public Class ValuesOfBlocks
    Private LargeBlockArmorBlock As Integer = 25    'Large Light Armor Block
    Private SmallBlockArmorBlockSteelPlates As Integer = 1  'Small Light Armor Block
    Private LargeBlockArmorSlope As Integer = 13    'Large Ligth Armor Slope 
    Private SmallBlockArmorSlopeSteelPlates As Integer = 1  'Small Light Armor Slope
    Private LargeBlockArmorCorner As Integer = 4    'Large Light Armor Corner
    Private SmallBlockArmorCornerSteelPlates As Integer = 1 'Small Light Armor Corner
    Private LargeBlockArmorInvCorner As Integer = 21    'Large Light Armor Corner Inverted
    Private SmallBlockArmorInvCornerSteelPlates As Integer = 1 'Small Light Armor Corner Inverted

    Public Function Value(ByVal BlockName As String) As Integer
        Dim _ret As Integer
        Select Case BlockName
            Case "LargeBlockArmorBlock"
                _ret = LargeBlockArmorBlock
            Case "SmallBlockArmorBlockSteelPlates"
                _ret = SmallBlockArmorBlockSteelPlates

            (...)

        End Select
        Return _ret
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick reply. I know my question may have been stupid or dumb but i wasnt quite sure how to phrase it, this should work perfectly. Thanks :)

Comment: Could you write this with a matrix or an array, this calculates how many components u need to builed each block of the blueprint and some blocks contain multiple components (Steel Plates, Computers, Interior Plates, Small Steel Tubes, Large Still Tubes, etc) so i was thinking either a matrix or an array would suffice

Comment: @LordComfy please mark Jimi's answer as the answer to show your gratitude.

Comment: Actually using a class definition containing all the block definitions i can easily do this using a dictionary of all the blocktypes deserealized straight from the games information which is what i have done now. The method above would have had me write each component for all 301 in game blocks, which would have taken ages and been really inefficient.

Comment: @Mary his answer was not a complete fix to the question only a partial solution. But yes ty for reminding me.